# Reading java spring properties for local

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have a project, called `Pikachu` and its structure is like this

```
src
 |-test
 |-main
    |-java
    |-config
        |-dev
        |-test
        |-prod
    |-resources
         |-pikachu.mvc.spring.xml
```

Each environment(dev, test, prod) has its own properties file(`.j2` format). Inside of `pikachu.mvc.spring.xml`, I set up bean for datasource

```java
// pikachu.mvc.spring.xml
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
  <property name="driverClassName" value="${db.driver}" />
  <property name="url" value="${db.url}" />
  <property name="username" value="${db.username}" />
  <property name="password" value="${db.password}" />
</bean>
```

each properties file under different environment is,

```
// dev/pikachuCfg.properties.j2
db.username = {{pikachu.db_username}}
db.password = {{pikachu.db_password}}
db.url = {{pikachu.db_url}}
db.driver = {{pikachu.db_driver}}
```

Once I deployed to each environment, it successfully load properties. However, when I launch it on the local(jboss11), it throws `PropertyAccessException`,

```
PropertyAccessException 1: org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationException: Property 'driverClassName' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not load JDBC driver class [${db.driver}]"}}
```

So here is my questions.
1. If I have to have properties file in `resources` folder, does it have higher order than properties files in the config folder? 
2. If it has higher order than other properties files in the `config` folder, how does this project use properties file in the different environment(dev, test, prod)?

Thanks in advance!
**EDIT**
I have read the document, (https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config).
However, I am still unclear which one has higher order between `config` folder and current folder(where spring.mvc.xml is located).

Comment: Why do you use xml configuration with Spring Boot? And have you read the docs? https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config

Comment: @SimonMartinelli Idk. my team uses xml configuration with Spring Boot. I have checked that document, but it was not clear for my questions I think. If I am wrong, please correct me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully this helps

1. Put one more application.properties file under config directory parallel to dev, test & prod
2. Add to it *spring.profiles.active=dev*
3. Keep this commented while going for test or prod environments

Comment: @jayko03 No.. it is to be put in properties file